# LDAP functionality not present. Either load the module ldap php module or use a php with ldap support compiled in

Tags: php, codeigniter, ldap

I'm new in Codeigniter development.

I want to implement AuthLDAP library. I copy all needed files in my application but when I want to open `http://localhost/AJAXPHPci/index.php/auth/login_form.php` I'v got error *LDAP functionality not present. Either load the module ldap php module or use a php with ldap support compiled in.*

Does anyone have same issue and can help me? Or can give me link to some tutorial how to implement this library?

Thanks!

Comment: you can type in on the CLI of your server `sudo apt-get install php5-ldap` if not ubuntu you will need to change `apt-get` to whatever your package manager is on your server. You would also need to restart apache/nginx or whatever your server is

Comment: I checked PHP extension php-ldap and error disappeared, that's good! But now when I go on my path http://localhost/AJAXPHPci/index.php/auth/login_form.php I got 404 Page not found error, that's means that path is ok, but can't display page. Do I have to check some settings in config or what?

Comment: are u trying to access the controller directly or are all you paths appended with `.php`. With CI the URL's are normally formatted like this: <domain + sub-directories>/index.php/<controller name>/<method name> so you could try take the .php from the end of your URL to see if that works, else you would have to show your controller and route code so I can see why its not working.

Comment: Ok, I found it. When I go on localhost/AJAXPHPci/index.php/auth/ I'v got page for login. Thank you a lot! I now have other issues about LDAP server, but that's other topic I think. It's so bad that there isn't one good tutorial about this library and LDAP.